# How to search through eclipse closed projects?

Tags: python, eclipse, search, project

Was asking if I could do a search on the entire eclipse library which includes my closed projects. I did a file search(Ctrl + H) but they only shows results for projects that are open.

Answer (score 0):

When a project is closed, it can no longer be changed in the Workbench and its resources no longer appear in the Workbench, but they do still reside on the local file system. Closed projects require less memory. Also, since they are not examined during builds, closing a project can improve build time.

A closed project is visible in the Package Explorer view but its contents cannot be edited using the Eclipse user interface. Also, an open project cannot have dependency on a closed project. The Package Explorer view uses a different icon to represent a closed project.